# Flash channels compared to Raiden

Tags: flash-channel

Can it be said, in a general sense, that [Flash channels](https://blog.iota.org/instant-feeless-flash-channels-88572d9a4385) and [Raiden](https://raiden.network/) are made for the same purpose? Both function in a way that a prepaid channel is being created and entities within exchange value off chain. Whenever any party decides to abandon the channel, they may do so.

Remark: I know the Tangle and Ethereum are two different implementations (Blockchain vs. DAG) however I think this question is still valid since they both fall beneath the DLT umbrella and it looks to me that they are designed to enable fast micropayments, off chain.

Comment: As far as I know, it is pretty much the same. In IOTA, however, you can create these channels without any fees

Comment: Seems like this is the case. I have found some references and will mash up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will conclude that both Raiden and Flash channels generally serve the same purpose. I'm basing my conclusion on [this blogpost](https://blog.iota.org/instant-feeless-flash-channels-88572d9a4385) alongside David Sønstebøs answer on [this Q&A session](https://answers.thenextweb.com/s/dominik-schiener-and-david-sonstebo-d0XXq0), I quote:

Question:

> What's your opinion about the Lightning Network upgrade for blockchains?

Answer:

> I consider it an ad-hoc half-measure to an inherently limited protocol. To me Lightning Network is only potentially useful for certain things, but even for those we have Flash Network